# Is there a Rails active record method I can call to get all @images?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have these two models:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images
end
```

and

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
end
```

To get all my articles I simply do this:

```
@article = Article.all.find(params[:id])
```

Then I do the following to get all images this article has:

```
@images = Image.where article_id: @article.id
```

Is there some active record method that I can call to get all my `@images`, rather than what I have above? I just wonder if there is a better way than what I am doing.

I tried `@article.images` but it only returned the relation without the data.

Comment: Did you try using @article.images.load ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
@article.images.all
```